# Custom EditTextPreference updating incorrect summary

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, androidx, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to implement a custom Preference `MyEditTextPreference` whose summary is an EditText, as opposed to the default TextView (see [preference.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml)). This lets me edit the summary directly by tapping on it.

My problem is: in my use-case, I have 2 (or more) `MyEditTextPreference` with different summary texts and a SwitchPreference which toggles the preferences' visibility on / off.

When I toggle their visibility multiple times, at some point one of the `MyEditTextPreference` will have the summary of the other one.

example:
**state**: "summary 111" | "summary 222"
**toggle visibility on & off**
**state**: "summary 111" | "summary 222"
**toggle visibility on & off**
**...**
**toggle visibility on & off**
**state**: "summary 111" | "summary 111"

Can someone please tell me what is it that I am doing wrong, or not understanding here? all I know is under the hood the list of Preferences are stored in a RecyclerView, but I'm not sure what to do with this information or where to look deeper.

MyEditTextPreference.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.settingspreferences.widget

import android.content.Context
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.preference.Preference
import androidx.preference.PreferenceViewHolder
import com.example.settingspreferences.R

class MyEditTextPreference : Preference {

    private var TAG = "ABC MSSEditTextPreference"
    private var editText: EditText? = null

    private var customSummary: CharSequence? = null
    private var textWatcher: TextWatcher? = null
    private var cursorPosition: Int = 0


    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        layoutResource = R.layout.my_edittext_preference
        TAG += "[$key]"
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        layoutResource = R.layout.my_edittext_preference
        TAG += "[$key]"
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        layoutResource = R.layout.my_edittext_preference
        TAG += "[$key]"
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int,
        defStyleRes: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
        layoutResource = R.layout.my_edittext_preference
        TAG += "[$key]"
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)

        editText = holder.findViewById(android.R.id.summary) as EditText
        editText!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        editText!!.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE

        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: editText.text = " + editText!!.text.toString())

        if (customSummary != null) {
            editText!!.setText(customSummary)
        } else {
            editText!!.setText("")
        }

        if (textWatcher != null) {
            editText!!.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        }

        textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                // Save the cursor position before text changed
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                // Update the custom summary when the text is changed
                customSummary = s
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                // No action needed
            }
        }

        editText!!.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
    }

    override fun getSummary(): CharSequence? {
        Log.d(TAG, "getSummary: super.getSummary()=${super.getSummary()}, customSummary=${customSummary}")
        return customSummary ?: super.getSummary()
    }

    override fun setSummary(summary: CharSequence?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setSummary: customSummary=$customSummary, summary=$summary")
        customSummary = summary
        super.setSummary(summary)
        if (editText != null) {
            editText!!.setText(customSummary)
        }
    }
}
```

my_edittext_preference.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            tools:background="@color/black"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_accessibility_animation" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:hyphenationFrequency="normal"
                android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
                tools:text="Title" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@android:id/summary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
                android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/title"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hyphenationFrequency="normal"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minWidth="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:paddingEnd="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
                tools:text="summary" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:background="#404040" />


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt (which launches SettingsFragment, which launches CustomSettingsFragment)

```kotlin
package com.example.settingspreferences

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, SettingsFragment())
                .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SettingsFragment.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.settingspreferences

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

R.xml.root_preferences

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="Custom Preferences">

        <Preference
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_ampos_settings_color_correction"
            android:key="high_contrast_mode"
            android:title="See custom preferences"
            android:fragment="com.example.settingspreferences.CustomSettingsFragment" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

CustomSettingsFragment.kt

```kotlin
package com.example.settingspreferences

import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.InputType
import android.util.Log
import androidx.preference.Preference
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
import androidx.preference.SwitchPreference
import com.example.settingspreferences.widget.MyEditTextPreference

class CustomSettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

    private val TAG = "ABC CustomSettingsFragment"

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.custom_preferences, rootKey)

        val switchPreference = findPreference<SwitchPreference>("switch_make_visible")
        val et1: MyEditTextPreference? = findPreference("cet1")
        val et2: MyEditTextPreference? = findPreference("cet2")

        et1!!.setSummary("Summary 1")

        et2!!.setSummary("000000")

        switchPreference!!.onPreferenceChangeListener =
            Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, newValue ->
                val newVal = newValue as Boolean
                et1.isVisible = !newVal
                et2.isVisible = !newVal
                true
            }
    }
}
```